# Disable submit button until hidden field has content

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a hidden field that is populated when the user does a specific AJAX call.  I want to find a way to disable the submit button until the hidden field is populated with content.

```
   <input  type="hidden" name="lat" id="t1">
    <input type="hidden" name="long" id="t2">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#yourForm').submit(function() {
    if ( !$('#t1')[0].value && !$('#t2')[0].value ) { return false; }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set it to disabled and enable it at the same place you're setting the hidden value. I think you're trying to make it harder than it is.

Comment: But what if the Ajax call is made internally by a third-party library, and the success callback is not available?

Comment: Also, forms can be submitted by pressing ENTER while a form input is focused. It is safer to disable the form submit directly from within the submit handler.

Answer (score 0):

Initially set:

```
<input id="GO" type="submit" style="display: none" />
```

After your ajax call:

```
$('#GO').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$('#t1, #t2').change(function() {
    var enable = $('#t1').val() && $('#t2').val();
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', enable ? null : 'disabled');
});
```

Just make sure your Ajax call triggers the change event of the hidden inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do the following:

In with the rest of my JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({ //ajax options go here
    success: function(result) {
        //Do the rest of your success stuff here.

        $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Then, in my HTML markup:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" disabled="true">Submit</button>
```